# Define foreign key in existing table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How would I define a **foreign key** between the tables in the example below? They have an identically named column, but I currently am unable to make joins.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String

engine = create_engine('my connection details', echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()

my_table = Table('my_table', 
    Base.metadata, 
    autoload=True, 
    autoload_with=engine, 
    schema='my_schema')

other_table = Table('other_table', 
    Base.metadata, 
    autoload=True, 
    autoload_with=engine, 
    schema='other_schema')

class MyClass(Base):
    __table__ = my_table

class OtherClass(Base):
    __table__ = other_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `ForeignKey`s should be automatically reflected by `sqlalchemy`. Maybe the fact that you have two different `schema`s is the reason why it does not work in your case.

Anyways, according to [Overriding Reflected Columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/reflection.html#overriding-reflected-columns), you should be able to do something like:

```
my_table = Table('my_table', Base.metadata, 
    Column("my_id", Integer, ForeignKey("[other_schema].other_table.my_id")),
    autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, schema='my_schema')
```